# PLSQL: Query to know how many CPUs are available for use in PARALLEL clauses

Tags: oracle11g

I am not sure if this could be possible using sql statement. 
I am looking for sql query to know number of CPUs available on hardware to be included in PARALLEL clause. We do not have access to our Linux environment and hence has we are seeking any possiblity to know this value. Is it possible using SQL? Kindly suggest.

Actually my index creation script is taking longer then expected time and it was implemented with "NOLOGGING PARALLEL COMPRESS" clause.

Kindly suggest if leaving number "N" in PARALLEL and COMPRESS clause is ok.

How Oracle manage the degree of parallelism in case we miss number of CPU information in PARALLEL clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sqlplus you can use the below command to see number of cpu.

```
show parameter CPU_COUNT;

SQL> show parameter CPU_COUNT;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
cpu_count                            integer     2
```

Alternatively you can query `v$parameter` to get the same value

```
SQL> select value   from v$parameter where name like 'cpu_count';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2
```

Creating an index with `NOLOGGING PARALLEL COMPRESS` is optional but they bring in some values when you use it. Compressed indexes save space and reduce CPU time cause they take less space. If you have to scan 100 blocks -- do 100 latches, 100 consistent gets that takes a certain amount of CPU. Now, if it is compressed -- you have to do many 60 blocks, 60% of the CPU as before. Apart you store more index entries per leaf block.

For how oracle works in parallel read below:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot @XING for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If the PARALLEL clause is specified but no degree of parallelism is listed, the object gets the default DOP. Default parallelism uses a formula to determine the DOP based on the system configuration, as in the following:

- For a single instance, DOP = PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU x CPU_COUNT
- For an Oracle RAC configuration, DOP = PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU x
  CPU_COUNT x INSTANCE_COUNT

you can query v$parameter to get the above two parameters name - cpu_count and parallel_threads_per_cpu

```
SQL> SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter WHERE UPPER(name) IN ('CPU_COUNT','PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU');
```